# Core Data NSInternalInconsistencyException (different this time)

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I know there are a million of these questions in SO, but this is different, and I am stumped.

I have a data model with about a dozen entities in it.  Code ran just fine.  Then I versioned the model, added an entity and a relationship, then updated the setting for the current versioned data model in the xdatamodeld file and am now getting NSInternalInconsistencyException when trying to access the new entity.

In my main VC I log the context, the persistent store coordinator, the managed object model, and all of the entities.  Everything looks as I would expect, including the entity I am trying to access.

I have blown the SQLite DB away, and let Core Data recreate it, and can see the table, with correct column types.

Everything looks correct.

Here is the fetching code:

```
- (void)fetchMissions {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Mission" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    missionsArray = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
}
```

Here is the output from:

```
NSLog(@"Entities : %@",[[self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel entities] valueForKey:@"name"]);


Entities : (
    Character,
    CharacterClass,
    CharacterCondition,
    CharacterObjective,
    CharacterPerception,
    Condition,
    Mission,
    Objective,
    Perception,
    PlayerCharacter,
    Scoreboard
)
```

I also see the detail for the Mission entity when I print out the entire managed object model with:

```
NSLog(@"MOM : %@", self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel);
```

The entity is dead simple... 3 columns, two are text/string and one is an integer.  Entity description in the model editor matches the table definition in SQLite.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I am an idiot...

Was not grabbing the MOC in my viewDidLoad as I was in other VCs, so while I was printing out the correct MOC from the delegate, I did not have a handle to it in the Mission VC.

Fixed.

Thanks for listening.  :)